# P(TT|T) in two coin tosses not 1/3?

Tags: probability, fake-proofs, paradoxes

So the question is, if two consequtive coin tosses occured and we know, in the aftermath, that at least of them resulted in a tails, what is the probability that they were both tails?

The common answer to this question is 1/3, with the arguement that there are four possible outcomes for two coin tosses: (HH, HT, TH, TT) and that by by knowing at least one tails, we eliminate HH so the sample space becomes (HT, TH, TT) in which only TT would satisfy the condition, hence 1/3.

However, here is what I think the correct way to represent this problem would be:

The sample space for two coin tosses = (HH, HT, TH, TT)
The sample space for two coin tosses, knowing that one yielded a tails= (H**T**, **T**H, **T**T, T**T**), where **bold** indicates that we know about that outcome. Obviously, in this way, the likelyhood of TT is 1/2.

Another way to think about this, is that on a probability tree, either we know about the first even giving a T, or we know abou the second event giving a T. Either way, there's a 1/2 chance that the other event lead to a T.

I tagged this as fake proof, because it goes against every other answer I've seen to this question, on this board or elsewhere, so I expect to be proven wrong, but I haven't seen this argument made anywhere else for the answer being 1/2.

Comment: **Hint:** If you reduce a point from a sample space, can it remain the original size ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another argument giving the answer $1/3$: Letting $TT$ stand for the event "Two tails" and $T$ stand for "At least one tails", we have
$$
P(TT \mid T) = \frac{P(TT\cap T)}{P(T)} = \frac{P(TT)}{P(T)} = \frac{1/4}{3/4} = \frac{1}{3}
$$

Yet another argument is this: Let a *lot* of people do two coin flips, and tell all who got two heads to leave the room. You're now in the "$\hphantom{}\mid T$" situation. Only one third of the people there flipped two tails.

What you're thinking about might be this: Pick a coin that was tossed tails. Then the probability that its partner was also tails is $1/2$. The difference between the two is that the $TT$ pairs are twice as likely to be picked in this way, compared to the "pick a random pair and examine it" way.

Because, in the end, that's what the conditional probability $P(A\mid B)$ means. It means "Repeat the entire experiment (e.g. flip two coins, or pick a family with three kids, or look at the top card of a deck) until you have a sample fulfilling $B$. What is the probability that it fulfills $A$ as well?"

Comment: On a related note, the seemingly paradoxical nature of the Monty Hall problem comes from more or less the same misconception.

Comment: You explaination at the end makes sense, but isn't the original text problem in fact the same as my interpretation because it specifies that you know already know that there is a T? You're looking at the probability of another T, if you know there is one T, not the probability that a T is followed by a second T.

Comment: @user3129805 You repeat the experiment (with equal probability of $HH, HT, TH$ and $TT$) until you don't get $HH$. That means that $HT, TH$ and $TT$ are the three possible outcomes, and they're equally likely (technically, you might include the probability $0$ event that you only get $HH$, and never finish). You will note that this means that the probability of two tails under these conditions is $1/3$. It's gone up from the $1/4$ probability it was before you removed $HH$ as a possible outcome.

Comment: I undrestand that the answer for the question is 1/3 but I tried to propose this as a false proof question because I want to see why my approach is wrong. In other words, what is my probability tree interpretation or the other one missing?

Comment: @user3129805 The first one is false because of what I said in my third paragraph: you go from picking a random pair that contains a tails and examining that, to picking a random coin that is tails, and examine the pair it belongs to. This skews the probability in favour of double tails. I can't really follow your probability tree explanation, but I would think the problem there is very similar.